# In SQLAlchemy, how to input a list and get eligible items in the table?

Tags: python, sql, django, sqlalchemy

Table A has two columns: `ID` and `name`

I want to input 3 ID and get 3 name, my way looks like

```
ID_list = [1,3,4]
DBSession.query(TableA).filter(or_(TableA.id == input_ID_list[0], TableA.id == input_ID_list[1], TableA.id == input_ID_list[2])
```

which looks quite foolish.

Is there a cleaner way to finish this job in SQLAlchemy, such as this:

```
DBSession.query(TableA).filter(TableA.id.in_(input_ID_list))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Already know the answer, there is a `in_` function

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ID_list = [1,3,4] 
DBSession.query(TableA).filter(TableA.id.in_(ID_list))
```